# Is it possible to run angular 1.x and Angular 5 simultaneously?

Tags: angularjs, angular5, ng-upgrade

Is it possible to run **Angular 1.x** and **Angular 5** simultaneously?

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, with some work.  I would assume you would have to have Angularjs 1.5 or higher for this to work successfully though.  I'm also assuming that the reason you want to do this is to try and maintain some kind of backward compatibility?  Otherwise you would just migrate to a newer version of Angular.

Here is an example running a hybrid app with Angularjs and Angurlar2, but I would think you could do the same in Angular 5 as well. [Configuration Tips to build Hybrid Angular 1 and Angular 2 project in real world](https://medium.com/@SevenLee/configuration-tips-to-build-hybrid-angular-1-and-angular-2-project-in-real-world-230b715629dc)

Comment: Angular 1.4.4 is the version, is it not possible then?

Comment: I don't know.  The link I referenced didn't give versions, so it may be possible.  Angularjs 1.5 first introduced components, prior to that you could create closures that resembled components, but they are not the same thing and components are the building blocks of Angular 2.